# Black desktop background instead of picture

Tags: desktop-background

I would like to set the following picture as desktop background, but Gnome 3.28.2 (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) doesn't recognize it. The desktop background is black.

[image: Astronomical picture]

Output of the command `ls -ld $HOME/Pictures`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 ata ata 4096 Jul 14 20:59 /home/ata/Pictures
```

Comment: I have no problem setting this as my wallpaper.

Comment: Have you tried any other pictures? Are you able to set your background at all or is it this particular photo?

Comment: @Kyle: Apart from the supplied desktop wallpapers Gnome does not recognize any other pictures in the /home/USER/Pictures directory.

Comment: But you can right-click on any image in the file manager and choose "set as wallpaper" , can't you?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: @Melebius I've added the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x $HOME/Pictures
```

Make sure that your `Pictures` folder is accessible by others.

Comment: @Melebius +x is interpreted *differently* for directories.  `+x` for directories gives traverse permissions, not executable permissions.  I suggest you read through `man chmod` to understand this.

Comment: @ThomasWard I know the difference but this answer seems to mix them together IMHO. Please read the comments to the question, too. I doubt missing execute permission is the problem here as OP can view the folder contents in file manager.

Comment: @ThomasWard I’ve just edited the answer in order to bring the contents into line.